# I need help with an only one command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been wanting Pokémon in Minecraft for a while now. I found A LOT of commands, but they weren't quite what I wanted. I finally found one I liked, but there's one problem: the Pokémon are disguised baby zombies, and I want to play on peaceful. Does anyone know of a quick way to convert this command from ***zombies*** to ***armor stands***? Here's the command I was using:
https://pastebin.com/kgPZy8c2

Comment: This command doesn't contain any zombies (already replaced?). Also please include commands or code snippets in your question instead of using external sources. We have a code tag for this.

Comment: *Zombies have AI, armor stand's don't.* They will probably just sit there, though I'm no expert on commands.

Answer (score 2):

Although you could transfer this to armour stands it would just stand there and not move but if what you want is mobs not to spawn naturally then you could just do

```
/gamerule doMobSpawning false
```

This will disable mob spawning naturally and then you could do

```
/effect @p minecraft:saturation 100000 10
```

You will need to do this first

```
/kill @e[type=!player]
```

So that all of the mobs already spawned die.

That way it will be like peaceful no hunger and no mobs spawning naturally but your baby zombie pokemons will still spawn.

If you want to have hunger then just don't do the second command.